# Convert MYSQL Timestamp to time_t

Tags: c++, mysql, datetime, time-t

I'm writing a multi-threaded program that needs to be able to check if a row requires updating and act accordingly.

I had problems using the built in date/time functions of MySql and so decided to just store the "lastupdate" timestamp as an integer in the table. However, I'm having problems converting this timestamp to time_t so that I can use the time functions with it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You made a mistake in the name of question `Convert MYSQL_ROW to time_t` instead of `Convert timestamp to time_t`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The MySql [timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) data type can be stored as a number in either YYYYMMDDHHMMSS,  YYMMDDHHMMSS, YYYYMMDD, or YYMMDD format.

In Unix and POSIX-compliant systems, [time_t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_t) is typically an integer which represents the number of seconds since the start of the Unix epoch: midnight UTC of January 1, 1970.

In MySQL you can use the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) and [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) functions convert between TIMESTAMP values and Unix timestamp values.

Query Example: `SELECT Unix_Timestamp(Date_Entered) FROM Foo;`

Answer (score 4):

Try FROM_UNIXTIME and TO_UNIXTIME and leave your dates as dates in the database.